# Remove / (slash) from dom using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have `dom` structure like

```
<div class="container">
    <span> test1 </span> 
    /
    <span> test2 </span> 
    /
    <span> test3 </span> 
</div>
```

which produces output like

```
test1/test2/test3
```

i am able to remove the `span` .. but not able to remove the `slash` from dom.. can any one please help me to remove the slash from dom so i can get output like

```
 test1test2test3
```

Comment: shouldnt this one work `$('span').text()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) of the element including [`Node.TEXT_NODE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType) afterwards [`.filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) can be used to get text nodes then use [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/).

```js
$('.container').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <span>test1</span> /
  <span>test2</span> /
  <span>test3</span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iteratate `.childNodes` of parent `.container` element, check if `.textContent` of current node contains `"/"`, if true call `.parentElement.removeChild` with current node as parameter.

```js
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
for (let node of container.childNodes) {
  if (node.textContent.indexOf("/") > -1) {
    node.parentElement.removeChild(node)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span> test1 </span> /
  <span> test2 </span> /
  <span> test3 </span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `children()` function and edit the `container` HTML.

```js
var $container = $('.container');
$container.html($container.children());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <span>test1</span> 
    /
    <span>test2</span> 
    /
    <span>test3</span> 
</div>
```